# Android mailing app to compose, send receive emails from all mailing servers in one app

Tags: android, email, outlook, gmail, yahoo

i just need some help regarding mailing servers, i am developing an app on android to fetch all emails from all mailing servers like (yahoo, gmail, outlook etc), i want to get all data (inbox, sent items, outbox etc) to my own app instead of using default app. what methods should i use?

I only have got this code, which can only send email using gmail API, i am not getting enough information to fetch all data

```
package com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail;
```

Comment: What you have posted is not a question within the SO guidelines. These are plain requirements for a complete system.

Comment: i actually just want to know if there is any single procedure which can do it all, or i have call each mailing server separately?